# C# - Convert Ethereum ABI Address To String (Solidity)

Tags: solidity, addresses, c#, .net

I'm new to Ethereum so please excuse my ignorance. Ethereum seems to have an ABI serialization protocol called Solidity. The spec is here:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI

I'm looking for a way to encode and decode contracts in C#. Specifically, I want to take an array of bytes (byte[]) and convert it in to a human readable Ethereum address as a starting point.

Here are a couple of libraries that I've cloned, but after sifting through the code, it's not immediately apparent how to achieve what I am trying to do:

https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum

https://github.com/sense2k/Ethereum.NET

Can someone point me to an example of how to convert a byte array to a human readable Ethereum string address?

Answer (score 0):

**In Solidity:**

Example of turning an Address into a Byte Array and then into a String:

```
/// @dev Function convert a Address to a String
/// @return Address as a string
function toString(address input) internal pure returns (string) {
    bytes memory byteArray = new bytes(20);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = byte(uint8(uint(input) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
    }
    return string(byteArray);
}
```

**In C#:**

Turning byte array into a String:

```
string address = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(addrByteArray, 0, addrByteArray.Length);
```

Where `addrByteArray` is the Address in Byte Array format.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but all I get back is garbled characters. The array that I am getting - in this case from my Trezor, is not encoded in UTF8 format.

Comment: what is the meaning of uint(input) here? Isn't input an array of bytes? Does't uint(input) convert the array to an array of uints?

Comment: The uint is the array index counter (like for i = 0; i++, but for Solidity). It extracts each byte out of the array, so long as that array is below 20 (an address will return a 20 byte array).

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance. But, isn't "i" the array index counter? In this case, there is a piece of code uint(input) . What operation does that perform?